# Separation of two ellipses defined by coordinates

Tags: python, opencv

I detected the object using OpenCV (Canny), and got two ellipses (almost circles). The center is determined by template matching, so it is not the exact center. The goal is to get the coordinates of each ellipse (almost circle) separately. I tried separating them by distance from the center, but since they are not ideal circles, it is not possible to get each one in its entirety.

Is there any possibility of using OpenCV?

[image: Image created using coordinates]

Source coordinates:
[text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IELRGsIQeVGJQClMBk_oBIzdiiNxANwo/view?usp=drive_link).